# jQuery remove a previously randomly selected and displayed paragraph and re-display a randomly selected paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

Right now my code allows me to click a button and display a paragraph at random. However, if I click the button a few times again it will display both items. How I would code this such that when I click the button a second time it will get rid of the previously displayed `<p>` and display a new randomly selected `<p>`? I was trying to use `$( "#foo").unbind( "click" );` but that doesn't work.

my jQuery:

```
$( "#toggleweight" ).click(function() {
  var set =Math.floor((Math.random()* $('p').length )+1);
  $.ajax({success:function(result){
    $( "#foo").unbind( "click" );
    $( "p:nth-child(" + set+ ")" ).fadeIn( 3200 );
    }});
});
```

my HTML:

```
    <div id="button">
      <a class="btn" href="#" id="toggleweight">Cool button. </a>
    </div>
    <div id = "button2">
      <% array = ["ASDF", "FDSA"] %>
      <% array.each do |display| %>
      <p class="btn" style="display: none"><%= display %></p>
     <% end %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fade out all P's, and oncomplete fade it back in

```
$.ajax({success:function(result){
        $( "#foo").unbind( "click" );
        $("p").fadeOut(400,function(){
            // onComplete code goes here
            $( "p:nth-child(" + set+ ")" ).fadeIn( 3200 );
        });
    }
});
```

You can use slide functions as well, or via position absolute fade them like a simple slideshow fades

Comment: Thanks @Martijn - what do you mean about the onComplete code?

Comment: got it - works great! `$( "#toggleweight" ).click(function() {
  var set =Math.floor((Math.random()* $('p').length )+1);
$.ajax({success:function(result){
        $( "#foo").unbind( "click" );
        $("p").fadeOut(400,function(){
            // onComplete code goes here
            $( "p:nth-child(" + set+ ")" ).fadeIn( 3200 );
        });
    }
});
})`